# How can I use a Tkinter input as a mathematical sum?

Tags: python, math, tkinter

I was a little bit discovering how Tkinter works. 
I made a little program, in which you can type (for example) the length of two sides. This is my code:

```
    from tkinter import *
from math import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("Lengte: %s\nBreedte: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Lengte").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Breedte").grid(row=1)

Label(master, text="Oppervlakte").grid(row=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

I didn't use any mathematics yet, simply because I don't understand how they work in Tkinter.

What I want is, to let the user type the two sides of a square (length & width, I did that part well), and that the program calculates the area of the square.

Help please!

**EDIT:**

```
   from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("Lengte: %s\nBreedte: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Lengte").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Breedte").grid(row=1)
Label(master, text="Oppervlakte").grid(row=2)

def show_entry_fields():
     area_label['Oppervlakte'] = str(Oppervlakte)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: Math in Tkinter works like math outside of Tkinter. You do have to make sure that you understand the difference between numbers and strings, which is likely the main sticking point for beginners.

Comment: Just a cautionary note: While it may be tempting to use eval to do things like `eval("3*5")` to do the task quickly, this is an improper and sometimes dangerous use of eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the entry widget's `.get()` method as you have to get whatever is inside of it.

What this returns is a string. So, to be able to perform mathematical operations with these inputs you will first need to convert them to ints / floats.

You can check if the input is an integer by using `isdigit()`. This will test if the string is an integer, which let's you be able to check this before casting the string to an `int` to avoid exceptions.

You can simply use a try / except for floats.

The `math` module seems to be an unnecessary import here. You can just use basic operations to do this built into Python.

Example: (I've assumed the inputs are actually integers here)

```
def show_entry_fields():

     length, width = int(e1.get()), int(e2.get())
     area = length * width
     print("The area is", area)
```

Going back to `isdigit`... You could check that they are indeed integers as mentioned previously. For example, if nothing (which would return as a blank string) or some other string was input into the entries and you tried to convert  (to an `int`) you would get the following error message:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'some_string'
```

You can avoid this by checking before conversion:

```
entry_one_value = e1.get()
if entry_one_value.isdigit():
    some_var = int(entry_one_value)
```

What about if you wanted to convert to a floating point number. You can just use a Try / Except as mentioned before:

```
entry_one_value = e1.get()
try:
    some_var = float(entry_one_value)
except ValueError:
    print("Error. Not a floating point number!")
```

**Edit**: After computing the area you will likely want to be able to display this in the GUI.

So, let's save a label widget as a variable so we can configure it's text. We will also split this into two lines, because whenever you `.grid()` a widget it returns None and thus we won't be able to actually use the reference to the widget.

```
 area_label = Label(master, text="N/A")
 area_label.grid(row=some_row)
```

Then, in the previous function you can just configure the labels text.

```
def show_entry_fields():

     ....
     area_label['text'] = str(area)
```

**Edit to edit your edit from my previously edited edit:**

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
     length, width = int(e1.get()), int(e2.get())
     area = length * width
     area_label['text'] = str(area)

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Lengte").grid(row=0)
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

Label(master, text="Breedte").grid(row=1)
e2 = Entry(master)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

area_label = Label(master, text="Oppervlakte")
area_label.grid(row=2)

Button(master, text='Quit', command=master.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment! But what I want is that the area is printed in a white field, just like the length/width. So that you only need the GUI, and not both

Comment: wait what? I don't get the last part, I get an error.

Comment: If `oppervlakte` label is the area label.. Then save it as a variable... grid it on the seperate line as you see in the last part. Then, you need to index `area_label['text']`. Text is a `key` of the widget. We're not indexing the actual text. To see a list of keys you can do `widget.keys()`. So, we're using `area_label[**'text'**] = 'new_text'` to reset the text.

Comment: I really don't get you...my fault of course, not yours. Look at my edit: can you please send me the script with what you mean? I probably get it if I see it.